# grpc python secure client fails to connect to server, csharp and cpp clients does not fail with same certificates

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

**client**

```
    creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=open(ca_cert_path, 'rb').read())
    channel = grpc.secure_channel(domain + ':' + str(port), creds)
```

**server**

```
    server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials([(server_key, server_cert)], server_ca, False)
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    # Add secure port
    server.add_secure_port(domain + ':' + str(port), server_credentials)
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()
```

**server logs highlights**

> TCP: 00000170AA577ED0 READ error=UNAVAILABLE: End of TCP stream
> [type.googleapis.com/grpc.status.int.grpc_status='14'] CANCEL PINGS:
> UNKNOWN:Secure read failed READY -> SHUTDOWN (close_transport, OK)
> notifying watcher 00000170AA4C08C0: READY -> SHUTDOWN (event_engine)
> WindowsEventEngine::00000170AA0E8260 cancelling shutdown why=UNKNOWN:
> Secure read failed

**client logs highlights**

> Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED. Channel state
> changed: ChannelConnectivity.TRANSIENT_FAILURE E0111
> 14:27:13.888000000 236656
> src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.cc:186]
> watch_completion_error: CANCELLED

Comment: The issue could be anything.  May be a encoding mismatch or a grpc version mismatch.
 
May be enable verbose logs on the server using GRPC_TRACE and GRPC_VERBOSITY?

1. Create channel using CPP client and capture logs on the server. 
2. Create channel using python client and capture logs on the server. 
3. Compare the above two logs to find out the differences.